# Recover a file with a wrong suffix?

Tags: libreoffice

I wrote a text Under Libre Office and wrongly named the file with a .txt suffix. And closed it. When I tried to open it. it was said corrupt. And was displayed in non understandable characters. What to do? I tried to rename it with .odt suffix. It changed nothing.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You haven't mentioned what operating system you are using, if it's Windows, goto control panel->folder options->View tab and untick 'Hide extensions for known file types'-apply, then go to file location and rename with correct suffix (.odt), it should ask you to confirm suffix change, you will be able to open it now.

Comment: @BernardBarthalay, if you open cmd.exe and navigate to the folder, and use 'dir' to show its contents, what is the extension for the file?